# cross-domain request jquery

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I need to create some JavaScript that does a cross-domain request.

The script must request a desired page and display it on the screen.

Need to do as well as this realised on facebook at display iframe application. How create this? Prease to demonstrate or give link on tutorial.

Thanks.

Comment: People are not here to code for you. Can you say what you tried, what are you facing a problem with. Please see [writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: Check out http://www.freelancer.com/, you can pay someone to do the work for you there.

Comment: -1 Please check out the link referred to by giddy

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at `JSONP` and `$.getJSON()` There are [lots of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross-domain%20request%20jquery) on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, and your question states no specifics.  It also contains horrible grammar that I attempted to edit but could still not fully understand.  Please be more specific.  Edit your questions if you wish to receive better answers than this one.